# Draggable paths with transform() method in Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, path, drag-and-drop, raphael

I'm trying to make a path draggable with the non-deprecated method `Element.transform()`. Here is the answer to make it with deprecated method `Element.translate()` :

[Making paths and images draggable in Raphael js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224359/making-paths-and-images-dragable-in-raphael-js)

When I simply replace `translate()` by `transform()`, my path come back to initial position very quickly :

```
drag(function (dx, dy) {
       var trans_x = dx - this.ox;
       var trans_y = dy - this.oy;

       this.transform("t" + trans_x + "," + trans_y);
       this.ox = dx;
       this.oy = dy;
     }, 
     function () {
       this.ox = 0;
       this.oy = 0;
     },
     function() {
     }
);
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution !

Just have to use the append syntax of transform() which is .transform("...t" + .. + ...)

So here is my final result :

```
drag(function (dx, dy) {
       var trans_x = dx - this.ox;
       var trans_y = dy - this.oy;

       this.transform("...t" + trans_x + "," + trans_y); //Just change this line
       this.ox = dx;
       this.oy = dy;
     }, 
     function () {
       this.ox = 0;
       this.oy = 0;
     },
     function() {
     }
);
```

and it works perfectly.